# jmx command line tool that does not require JDK

Tags: java, bash, jmx

I am trying to find a JMX cli client that can be used instead of jconsole.
I have tried jmxterm and really liked it.
However, is there a JMX command line tool out there similar to jmxterm that does not require JDK for its usage ?